# MS Word insists that "trans" has to be capitalized

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

Ok, so I transcribe interviews and many of these interviews are with trans people. This means that the word "trans" can get used over 100 times per document. Word's spell check stops at each and every instance of the word to insist that it should be capitalized. It gives the option to ignore, but not to "Ignore all". You can imagine how much extra time is taken up having to ignore more than 100 times.

I tried deleting the word from the dictionary, but of course can only delete from the custom dictionary -- although I have no idea whether it would help even if I could delete it from the other. I tried capitalizing the word so that the spell check would ignore it and then I could just search and replace when it was done, but now the spell check stops at each one because it believes it should have an apostrophe: "Tran's". (That doesn't even make sense.)

Any help here would be massively appreciated. I'm using Word 2013.

Comment: Have you tried *adding* trans to the dictionary?

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I deleted it from the dictionary and it wasn't capitalized in the dictionary. Now I've replaced it and it still insists it should be capitalized.

Comment: Instead of spellcheck dialog where button is greyed out, if you right-click on any instance of "trans" do you see "Ignore all" option in the pop-up menu?

Comment: Nice idea, but no. I get to ignore it once only.